# Можно ли в codeship сделать разные сборки для разных веток?

Tags: git, развертывание

Мне нужно собрать разные сборки для разных веток в codeship. Например если ветка master то делать npm run build-master, если develop то npm run build-dev. Можно ли как-то такое проделать в codeship?

Answer (score 1):

Переменная окружения [`CI_BRANCH`](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-integration/set-environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) - не оно?

PS если не поможет, то текущую ветку всегда можно прочитать в файле `.git/HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Не имею ни малейшего представления что такое codeship, но если команда `npm run ...` находится в версированном файле, то можно изменить этот файл в ветке develop.

Comment: Не лучшее решение - ведь после слияния в master это изменение тоже перейдет в master